# Team Foundation Server Build errors....NuGet?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget, nuget-package-restore

Im having build errors after building my Visual Studio Core repository from Team Foundation Server. My build order is Get Sources -> NuGet Restore, Build Solution, Publish Artifact

NuGet restore points to my NuGet.config file.

Looking at the error, it seems to me that my NuGet files are not being compiled. My Nuget files are pointing to a location in my file system. I can compile and run my program on VS but i cant successfully build using TFS.
Example errors:

project.assets.json not found, run a nuget restore to generate this file.
- After looking, I found the file in the same location it said not found?

The type or name space "System" could not be found
- Im getting this error for all 8 NuGet packages????

Answer (score 0):

The NuGet.config can't be pointing to **your** file system if you expect the restore to work on a machine other than yours. It has to be pointing to a location that the build server can access.

I'd recommend setting up a Package Management feed containing your packages.

Comment: I see, is there a way to convert NuGet packages to DLL files so I can just link them instead?

Comment: @Calidreaminn, you can rename NuGet packages to the end of the .zip file, then unzip the package, you will get dll files. Besides, pay attention that some packages has its dependencies.